# Transform vector of strings : skip elements based on the previous value

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, stl

I need to transform a vector of strings to lowercase but I need to preserve the *case* of the filenames. They are identified by previous string token "file" or "out".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

template <class T>
void print(const T& v) {
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), 
            std::ostream_iterator<typename T::value_type>(std::cout, "\n"));
}

std::string lowercase(const std::string& s) 
{
    std::string result(s);
    std::transform(result.begin(), result.end(), result.begin(), ::tolower);
    return result;
}

int main() {

    std::vector<std::string> tokens {"Col1", "Col2", "File", "FileIn.dat", "Out", "FileOut.dat"};
    std::transform(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), tokens.begin(), lowercase);

    // how to replace lowercase() with a lambda that will take the previous
    // element into account while converting an element into lowercase
    print(tokens);

    return 0;
}
```

In the above code the result should be

```
{"col1", "col2", "file", "FileIn.dat", "out", "FileOut.dat"};
```

preserving the case of the string after "file" and "out".

Is there a way to do this using `std::transform` and `lambda` functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is.  You can use a capturing lambda like this:

```
bool is_filename = false;
std::transform(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), tokens.begin(),
    [&is_filename] (auto &s) {
        if (is_filename)
            is_filename = false;
        else  
        {
            s = lowercase (s);
            is_filename = s == "file" || s == "out";
        }
        return s;
    });
```

Output:

```
col1
col2
file
FileIn.dat
out
FileOut.dat
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/i4qqzVvxcmbqhGfa)

Comment: Does `std::transform` guarantee in-order application of unary operator ?

Comment: @Hiroki Not according to cppreference, it seems, but their 'possible implementations' do.  I guess a ranged `for` loop would be safer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can capture some state, and set it based on what you see. However you shouldn't use `std::transform`, because it doesn't guarantee in-order traversal. You have to use `std::for_each`.

```
int main() {

    std::vector<std::string> tokens {"Col1", "Col2", "File", "FileIn.dat", "Out", "FileOut.dat"};

    bool toggle = true;
    auto lowercase = [&toggle](std::string & s) 
    {
        if (toggle)
        {
            std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), ::tolower);
        }

        toggle = (s == "file") || (s == "out");
    }

    std::for_each(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), tokens.begin(), lowercase);
    print(tokens);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do this using std::transform and lambda functions?

`std::transform` doesn't guarantee in-order application of operator.
Thus if we need to apply `std::transform` to this problem, the overload for binary operator would be preferable:

[**Live Demo**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vgKvF9lIfVOLeUj7)

```
std::vector<std::string> tokens {"Col1", "Col2", "File", "FileIn.dat", "Out", "FileOut.dat"};

{    
    // The first element must not be file name.
    tokens[0] = lowercase(tokens[0]);

    std::vector<std::string> dummy;        
    std::transform(
        std::next(tokens.begin()), tokens.end(), tokens.begin(),
        std::back_inserter(dummy),
        [](auto& target, const auto& prev)
        {            
            const auto prevLower  = lowercase(prev);
            const auto isFileName = (prevLower == "file") || (prevLower == "out");

            if(!isFileName){
                target = lowercase(target);
            }

            return "";
        });
}

print(tokens);
```